# UIViewController Container not showing ChildViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I tried to implement a left side panel, how ever when I implement, it seems that it won't show anything on aside from the container.

Here is my code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initCenter(screen: showVC)
}

func initCenter(screen: ShowWhichVC) {
    var presetingController: UIViewController
    showVC = screen

    if dashboardVC == nil {
        dashboardVC = UIStoryboard.dashboardController()
        dashboardVC.delegate = self
    }
    presetingController = dashboardVC
    if let con = centerController {
        con.view.removeFromSuperview()
        con.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
    centerController = presetingController
    view.addSubview(centerController.view)
    self.addChildViewController(centerController)
    centerController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}



private extension UIStoryboard {

    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    }

    class func leftPanelController() -> LeftPanelController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftPanelController") as? LeftPanelController
    }

    class func dashboardController() -> DashboardController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardController") as? DashboardController
    }
}
```

Note: `DashboardController` and `LeftPanelController` UI are written programmatically, does this something to do with it?  Thanks!

> Update GMS

`2018-06-24 02:05:46.791965+0800 Pegasus[32657:577667] Google Maps SDK for iOS and Google Places API for iOS version: 2.7.30514.0
2018-06-24 02:05:46.808461+0800 Pegasus[32657:577704] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2018-06-24 02:05:46.808596+0800 Pegasus[32657:577704] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57`

I think now it has something to do with the GMSMapview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! As thoroughly checking on it, what I found is that the `centerController` view size is set to `0`, so what I did is I add a size to it that bounds to the screen size.

```
centerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
```